# How to get genesis block value at new bitcoin source?

Tags: bitcoin

So I am working bitcoin source 0.15.1

chainparams.cpp script,

Line 120~130,

Trying to find new genesis block's value when starting new.

So I googled many articles, forum, but not yet find working solution.

Unlike v0.8, there Debug.Log file itself seems does not generated even after write printf at source.

Why and how to get to know my genesis block value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chainparams.cpp contains a line of code that checks whether the chain’s genesis block is equal to a specified hash.

You can see an example for the line here:

```
 hashGenesisBlock = genesis.GetHash();
 assert(hashGenesisBlock == uint256("9915158279673d101912be80f25c20627f1dd8bf5231e7c46bfec5ed19737f44"));
```

To print it the hash of the genesis block, you can use

```
printf("genesis.GetHash = %s\n", genesis.GetHash().ToString().c_str());
```

Which prints the genesis block in terminal or debug.log

reference : [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/42135/problem-in-creating-genesis-block-twister-core-using-ubuntu-and-qt-creator-ide)

Comment: Thanks, but when I try to recompile, (typed 'make') error says 
[Makefile:741:recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make : *** [all-recursive] error 1

Comment: show the complete make in terminal or else try to configure once again

Comment: Thanks for comment. now I delete folder and downloaded from git, started again,  pasted this code

Comment: hashGenesisBlock = uint256("0x01")
if (true && genesis.GetHash() != hashGenesisBlock)
        {
            Logprintf("recalculating params for mainnet.\n");
            Logprintf("old mainnet genesis nonce: %s\n", genesis.nNonce.ToString().c_str());
            Logprintf("old mainnet genesis hash:  %s\n", hashGenesisBlock.ToString().c_str());
            // deliberately empty for loop finds nonce value.
            for(genesis.nNonce == 0; genesis.GetHash() >

Comment: bnProofOfWorkLimit; genesis.nNonce++){ } 
            Logprintf("new mainnet genesis merkle root: %s\n", genesis.hashMerkleRoot.ToString().c_str());
            Logprintf("new mainnet genesis nonce: %s\n", genesis.nNonce.ToString().c_str());
            Logprintf("new mainnet genesis hash: %s\n", genesis.GetHash().ToString().c_str());
        }

Comment: based on this site, 

http://dillingers.com/blog/2015/04/18/how-to-make-an-altcoin/

Comment: and recompile by make, then cd Desktop/litecoin/src

and then typed './litecoind' to check genesisblock's nnonce and hash. But nothing happened now 10 minutes passed. Am I doing right?

Comment: and I found that after type 'make', bunch of errors occured..about 'ToString'

Comment: I would suggest an easy method to get the genesis block using python  https://github.com/lhartikk/GenesisH0   Try changing the default parameters in the Python code to match your coin

Comment: Thx, but actually I did that too. But now, how to generate genesis block?

Comment: use that genesis hash and parameters in your coin and make it also don't forget to run 'make install'. Run the litecoind thenen the genesis block will automatically generate

Comment: Thx, I didn't 'make install', only did first time. So I did 'make install' but suddenly litecoin folder capacity become over 2 giga, ubuntu system's total hard is 20g (inside virtualbox), and become system itself unstable (can't run terminal, can't search anything from all apps). Is this normal? How much capacity need to run 'make install'?

Comment: for use [GenesisH0], what nonce value should I input? and source also should I revise? 
currently, 
........
genesis = CreateGenesisBlock(1519112885, 2084524493, 0x1e0fff0, 1, COIN);

Then, what value should I input there? First is time, I input by date+%s, about others, I don't know exclude COIN value.

Comment: I did [python genesis.py -a scrypt -z "Now is 2018-02.." -t 1519112885 -n 0 ]  but this says 459hours of searching work needed, so I stopped by ctrl+c key.  Is this right way? How to avoid so long wait time?

Comment: Where can I get pubkey value? Its used to many place like GenesisH0 or others.

Comment: I used GenesisH0, but still got error at final debug.log sentence says, 'Errors in block header at CBlockDiskPos(nFile=0, nPos=8)'